# How to consume N arbitrary arguments by name (position not guaranteed) and pass on the rest to a subcommand?

Tags: bash, shell

So for instance, if the shell script itself were to consume `-env` and `-local`, it would then need to pass on all other arguments (without knowing their number or ordering) EXCEPT `-env` and `-local` to some other script, while pulling out the values of `-env` and `-local` for its own personal use.

If the arguments the script were to consume were guaranteed to be the first ones it would be possible to use `shift` then and pass on the arguments inside `"$@"`, but since they're not that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate a new array with the remaining arguments.

```
#! /bin/bash
newargs=()
env=0
local=0
for arg ; do
    case $arg in
        (-env=*)
            env=${arg#-env=} ;;
        (-local=*)
            local=${arg#-local=} ;;
        (*)
            newargs+=("$arg") ;;
    esac
done

echo Env: $env
echo Local: $local
printf Args:' '
printf '%s ' "${newargs[@]}"
```

To extract the values from the `-arg=val` tuples, I used parameter expansion: `#` removes the given pattern from the beginning of the variable.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified. None of the arguments are switches. They are all in the format `-env=prd -local=true`, etc. In that situation, how can you iterate over the key-value pairs and pass them on? Thanks for your help so far :)